# Tap interface within a virtual machine has NO-CARRIER

Tags: virtual-machines, openvpn, kvm-virtualization, tap

I am trying to hook up a virtual machine to a host using openvpn.
When i create   a tap interface within the virtual machine using:
/usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev tap1
The state of the tap interface is always "NO-CARRIER"

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:07:55:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 12.1.1.2/24 brd 12.1.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe07:55b5/64 scope link tentative dadfailed 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br-ex: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.100.2/24 scope global br-ex
    inet6 fe80::3c23:adff:feb3:6d9d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: tap1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 100
    link/ether ce:e9:4a:1d:80:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Any ideas why this could be happening? 
I have checked to see the permissions of /dev/net/tun and it seems fine:

```
root@ip-10-66-210-99:~# ls -l /dev/net/tun
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 200 2014-02-15 07:15 /dev/net/tun
```

On the host itself there seems to be no issues. 
What am i missing?

Comment: Figured out the issue. The tap interface needs an application tied to it. Once I start the openvpn service, the tap interface state transitions to "RUNNING"

Comment: If you figured it out, you should write an answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it turns out was that the tap interface has to have an application associated with it for it to be in the "RUNNING" state.
Once i started the Openvpn service binding to tap0, the state moved to "RUNNING"